# Doctrine ORM - Relationship between same object

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

im stuck implementing aa probably easy database relationship.

I have an ORM object like

```
{ id, name, type , relationships }
```

and an relationship object

```
{ relationshipType, object1 , object2 }
```

What i try to accomplish is that when i create a relationship beween two objects i want to see the relationship object in both objects in the "relationships" collection.

Right now, only e.g. object 1 has the relationship object since thats the property with the "inversedBy" keyword.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out the `bidirectional` relationships here -> https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im aware of the bidirectional relations. I use them frequently in my project but always to relate to another object.

What i need here is to have something like a self-reference with an additional field with access to the relationships-collection on both linked objects.

Answer (score -1):

It should looks like this:

```
class ClassA {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ClassB", mappedBy="objectA")
     */
    private $objectsB;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ClassB", mappedBy="objectB")
     */
    private $objectsA;
}
```

---

```
class ClassB {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $relationshipType;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ClassA", inversedBy="objectsB")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $objectA;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ClassA", inversedBy="objectsA")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $objectB;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
Thats what it looks like right now. I was just wondering if there is a way to have both relations inside of one list element ( and i dont mean to merge the two collections ).

Comment: @WhiteRabbit It's possible yes, though depending on how you want it, you might have to do it manually. First make your CRUD for this with command line tools. It will generate a form for this. If it's not what you need, then search a bit here first, solution might already exists. Else just ask away with a new question.